# Reading multiple files, and keeping a set of data for each file.

Tags: c++, static

I want to read a file and save its header in a variable so that when I am rewriting(overwriting) that file, I can just paste the header and carry on with printing the rest of the modified file. The header, in my case, does not change so I can afford to just print it out. Here is my code inside the class:

```
.
.
.
static char headerline[1024];

static int read(const char* filename){
fget(var,...;
    for (int i=0; i<1024; ++i){
        headerline[i] = var[i];
    }    
.
.
.
}

int write(filename){
fprintf(filename, headerline);
//printing rest of file
.
.
.
}
```

The code successfully prints the line it saved while reading the file. However, my problem is that it saves the header of the file it read the last time. So if i have two files opened and I want to save the first one, then the header of the second file is written to the first one. How can I avoid that? If static map is a solution, what exactly is that?

Secondly, what would be the best way to print the whole header(5-8 lines) instead of only one line as I am doing now.

Comment: As a general rule in life, if someone suggests "X" as a solution to your problem and you don't know what "X" is, you should ask that person "What is X?" .

Comment: If I could, I would already have. Consider he's dead.

Comment: @detraveller: Sorry for your loss, but try to ask the question when they suggested the answer. Going out of a conversation without understanding what was said is never good.

Comment: To me these words just mean a static data member ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1b5y48f.aspx ) which happens to be of type map, i.e., std::map ( http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html ). In other words, they have two separate meanings which I can juxtapose in one expression so that the first one qualifies the second: "static map", "Canadian architect", "red apple".

Comment: Make a class that represents files and then store the header in the instance it belongs to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the problem that needs solving is that you are reading multiple files, and want to keep a set of data for each file.

There are MANY ways to solve this. One of those would be to connect the `filename` with the `header`. As suggested in a comment, using `std::map<std::string, std::string>` would be one way to do that.

```
static std::map<std::string, std::string> headermap;



static int read(const char* filename){
static char headerline;
fget(var,...;
    for (int i=0; i<1024; ++i){
        headerline[i] = var[i];
    }   
    headermap[std::string(filename)] = std::string(headerline);

...

int write(filename){
  const char *headerline = headermap[std::string(filename)].c_str();
 fprintf(filename, headerline);   
// Note the printf is based on the above post - it's wrong, 
// but I'm not sure what your actual code does.
```

Comment: Thanks. So the key should be the name of the file I am reading? In my case, the name of the file is `File* fp = ...`. How do I convert the name of type `FILE*` to `string`?

Comment: I suppose you can use almost anything that is unique (and you will of course need to use the appropriate type - since your example code says "const char *filename", I used that. A `FILE *` is only unique as long as you don't close the other ones. You may need to restructure your code a bit to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should use different header variables for different files.