# Saving a paragraph in map and printing - Not Working

Tags: c++, dictionary, header

This is related to the answer to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16543042/reading-multiple-files-and-keeping-a-set-of-data-for-each-file) by Mats Petersson.

According to his method, I can successfully save the line in the header and print it out later whenever I want. However, I now want to save the whole header to print it later. I am using append() to fulfill that purpose. But it's not working.

Here is the code that is outside the two functions:

```
static map<string, string> headermap;
static char headerline[1024];
```

Here is the code for the **reading function**:

```
string paragraph;

for (int i=0; i<8; ++i) {//8 lines of the header
    fgets(buffer,1024,fp);
    if(buffer[0] == '#'){
        paragraph = paragraph.append(buffer);
    }
}

headermap[filename] = paragraph;
```

Here is the code for the **writing function**:

```
const char *headerline = headermap[filename].c_str();
fprintf(fp, headerline);
```

Previously I was using `headerline[i] = buffer[i];` instead of `paragraph.append(buffer);` in the reading function. And `headermap[filename] = headerline;` instead of `headermap[filename] = paragraph;`.

When I print, nothing is printed to the output file. As i said before, previously when I tried to print just one line, it works fine.

Comment: `paragraph.append(buffer);` by itself is fine, no need for the assignment. Where are you using the `i` term? It looks like you just read 1024 characters 8 times without splitting on line ending ('\n').

Comment: I am not using the i term anywhere. I am just reading 8 lines. And i know i don't have the \n but that is a formatting problem, my question is why is `headerline` empty when i print it?

Comment: I am guessing that the `if(buffer[0] == '#')` line is stopping everything from going into paragraph. Is the first line you're reading start with a '#' without any starting whitespace (can't have a blank first line or any comments)? If not then buffer[0] probably won't ever trigger that condition.

Comment: Each line starts with #. No space or anything.

Comment: Are you saying that the only difference between the working code and the non-working code is the one line that changed from `paragraph = buffer;` to `paragraph = paragraph.append(buffer);`? No other changes?

Comment: CORRECTION: Previously I was using `headerline[i] = buffer[i];` and NOT `paragraph = buffer`. And `headermap[filename] = headerline;` instead of `headermap[filename] = paragraph;`. I will edit the question to reflect that. Sorry for the missing info

Comment: Is `paragraph` declared locally in the **reading** function? If so, it will not be accessible outside.

Comment: Yes. And that was one mistake. I have declared it outside now. But still not working.

Comment: Also, it is a bad idea to declare `headerline` in two places. You don't need it in the writing function at all, you can just do `fprintf(fp, headermap[filename].c_str())`.